# Can Anyone an Hint with the following SQL

Tags: sql

imagine i have a table like this

```
Bikename Username NumOfUsages LastTimeOfUsage
Bike1    Haldi    5            2018-12-13 12:00:00
Bike1    Torte    1            2018-08-15 12:00:00 
Bike2    Haldi    3            2018-12-15 12:00:00
Bike3    Manne    2            2018-09-16 12:00:00
Bike3    Torte    5            2018-09-16 12:00:00
```

now i wants a Result like this

```
Bikename Username NumOfUsages LastTimeOfUsage
Bike1    Haldi    5            2018-12-13 12:00:00
Bike2    Haldi    3            2018-12-15 12:00:00
Bike3    Torte    5            2018-09-16 12:00:00
```

as you can see i wants to have the Entry with the MAX NumofUsages only

Thanks for your Help so much...

Comment: Tag the DBMS (i.e. `MySQL`, `SQL Server`, etc..) that you are using.

Comment: So, to be clear - for each distinct `Bikename` value, you want the Username, NumOfUsages and "LastTimeOfUsage" that correspond to the highest number of `NumOfUsages`? What should happen in the even of a tie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `row_number()` maximum dbms support

```
select * from 
(
select *, row_number() over(partition by bikename order by NumOfUsages desc) rn
from table_name
)t where t.rn=1
```

Comment: Probably worth mentioning `RANK` as well, since we don't know their disposition towards ties yet.

Comment: This Soulution is the Best for my case… THX a Lot

Answer (score 5):

You want *correlated* subquery :

```
select b.*
from Bikes b
where b.NumOfUsages = (select max(b1.NumOfUsages) from Bikes b1 where b1.bikename = b.bikename);
```

By this way, it will return entire row for maximum `NumOfUsages` for each `bikename` since it has referenced from outer query with `subquery` (i.e. `b1.bikename = b.bikename`).

Comment: Thx for your answer, can you explain it deeper.

What is t1 here ?

Comment: Imagine my Tablename is Bikes, how a can do it?

Comment: @RoXTar - `t1` (now `b1`) is an alias. The table is referred to *more than once* in this query, and you use aliases to distinguish between the different references.

Comment: In this TOP sultion i have a Problem with doubles, if 2 Users have exact the same NumOfUsages…

Comment: @RoXTar. . . In that case what do you want in result ? For instance it will return both usres which has maxumum `NumOfUsages`.\

Comment: I would take the User with the LastTimeUsage

Comment: Who would i take the youngest LastTimeUsage in Case of  a double

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify the SQL flavor in your question, but in most cases simply group by the `bikename` and take `max(numOfUsages)` (and order by that as well)

Comment: If they want `LastTimeOfUsage` and `Username` in their result set, most SQL flavours don't allow only `GROUP BY` on the `bikename` and only aggregating the `NumOfUsages`.

Comment: True, my background is on MySql mostly, which does allow this :)

Comment: Yes, but you wouldn't make use of that MySQL extension (which isn't enabled by default any more) if (as here) the other columns weren't functionally dependent upon the group by columns :-)